# Как записать в коллекцию hashmap элементы arraylist

Tags: java, android

**пытаюсь добавить mImageViews/soundsRawResIds элементы этих двух массивов в imageCountru**
коллекцию mImageViews необходимо добавить в imageCountru в виде ключей

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> imageCountru = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> soundsRawResIds = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Integer> mImageViews = new ArrayList<>();

public void ininitialize() {
    mImageViews.add(R.drawable.russia);
    mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litva);
    mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litva);
    mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litva);
    mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litva);
    mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litva);
    mImageViews.add(R.drawable.litva);

    soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.belarus);
    soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.russian);
    soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.japan);
    soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.litva);
    soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.england);
    soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.finlandia);
    soundsRawResIds.add(R.raw.france);

}

public void add() {
  //тут пытаюсь добавить mImageViews/soundsRawResIds элементы этих двух массивов в imageCountru
}
```

в другом классе вывожу только значения ключа

```
 void some() {

    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> it = ima.imageCountru.entrySet().iterator();
            it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = it.next();
        int n = entry.getValue();
        mAdapter.addItem(n);
    }

}
```

Comment: Эм, а по какому ключу вы хотите туда что-то добавлять?

Comment: @GenCloud
коллекцию mImageViews необходимо добавить в imageCountru в виде ключей

Comment: А что будет значениями в `imageCountru` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> mImageViews = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer, Integer> imageCountru = new HashMap<>();
//блок записи add
imageCountru.put(mImageViews, value);
```

Comment: ну смотрите уже сами, что Вы по ключу уже хотите вытягивать из мапы

Comment: это чертовски плохо складывать в map значения с mutable ключами, есть шанс их никогда от туда не достать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.